# Equal integrals, circles, opposite directions

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I've found this equality in my complex analysis book, but I don't see why it is true. Could you help me understand it?

$$\int _{\partial D(1,1)} \frac{dz}{(z-1)(z+1)} = \int _{- \partial D(-1,1)} \frac{dz}{(z-1)(z+1)}$$

(I can see that we integrate over two circles in opposite directions. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Rewrite
$$
\int_{\partial D(1,1)}\frac{dz}{(z-1)(z+1)}=\int_{\partial D(1,1)}\frac{f(z)}{(z-1)}dz
$$

where $f(z)$ have no zeros in $\partial D(1,1)$. What is the value
of this integral ?

Similarly do it for the other integral.

Comment: We can use Cauchy's formula to "compute" this integral, right? $(1,0)$ in inside the circle over which we integrate, so the value of the integral above is $2 \pi i f(1) = 2 \pi i \frac{1}{2} = \pi i $. When it comes to the other integral, $(-1,0)$ is also inside $D(-1,1)$, here $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-1}$ and the value of the other integral is $2 \pi i \frac{1}{-1-1}= - \pi i$. By the way, the minus sign before $\partial D$ only means that we have to put minus before the integral?

Comment: @Hagrid - Yes, you got it right!

Comment: Uff, thanks :D So, could you explain to me a bit why the minus sign stands next to the $\partial D (-1,1)$ an not before the whole integral?

Comment: @Hagrid - This is part of the question that asks you to understand that going over this circle the other way around (i.e clockwise and not anti-clockwise) means that the integral value would be minus the value were we to go over the path the regular way

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you again.